# is 400w going to be okay with ATI 5750?

Tags: power-supply

I am going to buy ati 5750 for multi monitors. I have the following spec..

CPU: Q6600
RAM: 4gb
HDD: single 60gb ssd
USB: using 7 usbs so far

am I going to be okay with 400w power supply?

Comment: It is most important to have enough amperage on the 12v rail powering the video card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I need to know if I have enough power supply for my components, I go here: http://extreme.outervision.com/psucalculatorlite.jsp

Comment: wow..the website is extremely helpful! thanks a lot!